# line-through used in a class doesn't do anything when is clicked

Tags: javascript, css

trying to get a line through to work when i click on one of the li's, im doing a follow along video and i cant figure out the mistake, ive made sure a few times that the files are saved to the same location. heres the code in js:

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
    lis[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        this.style.color = "green";
    });

    lis[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
        this.style.color = "black";
    });

    lis[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        this.classList.toggle("done");
    });
}
```

and the code in css:

```
.done {
     text-decoration: line-through;
    opacity: 0.5;   
}
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Todo List Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="todos.css">
</head>
<body>

    <ul>
        <li>Wash cat</li>
        <li>Feed cat</li>
        <li>Feed cat to dog</li>
    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="todos.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please make a [MCVE]. I can't reproduce your problem https://jsfiddle.net/2kpqjcr5/

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a sufficient description of a problem. Are you saying that nothing happens when you click? How about when you mouseover/out? Does something happen but not what you expect?

Comment: Your code should work just fine. Any error in your console by any chance? (Ctrl+Shift+i for Chrome)

Comment: You may be using an unsupported browser (IE?). Try looking up whether the styles/scripts you are using are supported by your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your linking of js code and css are incorrect,
Run and click this on **li** it's working fine.

Also note that the "type" attribute of elements  `<link>` and `<script>` are  optional.

```js
 var lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    
    for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
     lis[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
      this.style.color = "green";
     });
    
     lis[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
      this.style.color = "black";
     });
    
     lis[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      this.classList.toggle("done");
     });
    }
```

```css
.done {
     text-decoration: line-through;
    opacity: 0.5;   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Todo List Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="todos.css">
</head>
<body>

    <ul>
        <li>Wash cat</li>
        <li>Feed cat</li>
        <li>Feed cat to dog</li>
    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="todos.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```